# Java Parse class name from sources

Tags: java, class, parsing

I'm trying to parse the class name:

```
public class Script {


}
```

And I'm using regex at the moment but it doesn't work as good as I though, my regex

```
class\s+(.*?)\W
```

But when things like extends and implemented comes in it's breaking itself.

I'm making a script that downloads sources from pastebin and auto saves it.

Thanks.

Comment: Try to be stricter about the characters a name can contain. For example it can't contain any whitespace characters.

Comment: Doesn't reflection only work with compiled files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `class\s+(\w*)\s*`

This would also handle the case of `class Classname{` whitout a space after the Classname

Answer (score 2):

This could do the trick :

serach for all characters excepts spaces or bracket
`class\s+([^\s{]+)\s*`

Comment: The Problem with class\s+([^\s]+)\s is, that it would return 'ClassName{' as result, if a space is missing between the ClassName and '{' - example: 'class ClassName{'

Comment: you are right, i updated the regexp to stop if there is a space or a "{"